# Facebook can't read my site

Tags: web-scraping, preview, facebook-opengraph

I have a wordpress blog on brightphoto.se and everytime I updated with a new blogpost a post a link to it on my brightphoto-page on Facebook.

A few days ago the preview that facebook normally do when you post a link stopped working.
I have tried to test the page with the debugger tool and first I thought that I hade wrong info on my blogsite due to the "error scraping page: Bad response code" but now I fixed that but I still got errors and.

I also asked my some of my friends so post links from the blog on their wall but Facebook never show any preview any more... why?

If I look on the graph API-page I get

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
       "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

Bug is known to fb developers, and "assigned":
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/209018432505064